# Compare two files with first column and remove duplicate row from 2nd file in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I will ask my question with an example. I have 2 files:

File # 1

```
002948998 752986QAK NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948932 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948933 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000
```

File #2

```
002948998 752986QAK NTR974VTS 0000000    
002901998 752986KFK NTR974MTS 0990000
```

Desired output :

```
002948998 752986QAK NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948932 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000    
102948933 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000    
002901998 752986KFK NTR974MTS 0990000
```

Note: there is no gap (enter) between the rows.

I'd like to compare file 1 and file 2 using their first columns and remove the entire row from file 2 if they match in file 1. I'd also like to save the results to a 1st file or a new file, file #3 which contains all the entries from file 1 and file 2 ( without the duplicates from file 2). Please advise a good resolution in shell script.

currently i am using :

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)' file1 file2 > file3
file3 >> file1
```

Comment: If one of the answers provided here solved your question, then you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Does this not do what you want?

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u > file3
```

This will sort the output, which may not be what you want, but passing the `-u` ("unique") flag to `sort` will cause it to remove all duplicate lines.

If the duplication is only in the first column, you can add a field specifier:

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u -k1,1 > file3
```

If you have blank lines, you can get rid of those any number of ways. Pipe the whole thing through `grep .` or, if the blank lines have spaces, `grep '[^ ]'`, etc.

Comment: This won't give OP's expected output as output will be sorted.

Comment: could you please explain the code a bit. thank you .

Comment: this is adding an enter in the beginning of the new file . i don't have an issue with output being sorted. but i don't want my file starting with an empty line ( enter). data is starting from 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1];print;next} !($1 in a)' f1 f2 > file3

cat file3
002948998 752986QAK NTR974VTS 0000000
102948932 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000
102948933 752986QSC NTR974VTS 0000000
002901998 752986KFK NTR974MTS 0990000
```

**Explanation:**

```
FNR==NR    - Execute next block for 1st file only
a[$1]      - Create an associative array with key as `$1` (first field)
print      - prints entire row from 1st file
next       - move to next row
!($1 in a) - Execute this block for 2nd file, it means print all rows from 2nd file when
             `$1` is not in array `a`
```

Comment: will this save the results in a file ? if yes, could you please explain how. sorry for questions. i am a newbie to shell scripting.

Comment: Yes I added `> file3` to make it save output in a file. Adding explanation.

Comment: no, it does not . it is adding the rows even though 1st is same and if 2nd column is different. the whole row is being compared. i just want to compare 1st column.

Answer (score 0):

Simlilar to @Mark Reed's answer, but without the sorting, you can use `uniq`, like that:

```
cat file1 file2 | uniq --check-chars=9 > file3
```

It will con**cat**enate file1 and file2 and give this concatenation to the `uniq` command. This command keeps the unique lines of its input (removes duplicates, by keeping only the first occurence). Then, the output is stored in file3.
`--check-chars=9` checks only the first 9 characters of each line for duplicates. You can find more options in [the man page of uniq](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq).

If the first column is not of fixed length (9), then you could use:

```
cat file1 file2 | uniq > file3
```

However, the comparison then would not be only based on the first column, as you require, but on the whole line instead.